# Formats for writing and/or submitting Statement of Purpose

Tags: phd, statement-of-purpose

I am going to submit my SOP for the Ph.D. application. I just want to know if there is any standard format for organizing the SOP such as should I include a title, do I have to write my name, page number and so on. The university where I am going to apply, does not have any specific information or guidance on the format of SOP. Therefore, I would be grateful if anybody helps me with this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: When I read an application, none of these format issues matter. But a few people might print out your SOP (instead of reading it on line as I do) and might have a stack of SOPs to read. For these people, you should have your name on the SOP.  Apart from that, as far as I can see, no one will care about the format.